# Join Statement using Query builder with multiple where clause

Tags: sql, laravel, join

I have a Query builder statement below and I would want to introduce another condition to the query. However, I can not get this right.

This query works fine;

```
$content = DB::table('subscribed_services as a')
->join('scheduled_messages as b', 'a.id', '=', 'b.subscribed_services_id')
->join('subscription_services_msisdn as c', 'a.id', '=', 'c.subscribed_services_id')
->whereRaw('DATE(b.scheduled_at) = CURDATE()')
->selectRaw('b.message, c. phone_number, a.username, a.password')
->distinct()
->get();
```

I would want to introduce another where statement; this `->whereRaw('DATE(c.sent_time) != CURDATE()')`. Meaning the query above should only pick values where subscription_services_msisdn.sent_time DATE(c.sent_time) IS NOT EQUAL to Current Date CURDATE().

Anyone lead me here. Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain as many where conditions as you want, so just add another `whereRaw` to the chain:

```
$content = DB::table('subscribed_services as a')
    ->join('scheduled_messages as b', 'a.id', '=', 'b.subscribed_services_id')
    ->join('subscription_services_msisdn as c', 'a.id', '=', 'c.subscribed_services_id')
    ->whereRaw('DATE(b.scheduled_at) = CURDATE()')
    ->whereRaw('DATE(c.sent_time) <> CURDATE()')
    ->selectRaw('b.message, c. phone_number, a.username, a.password')
    ->distinct()
    ->get();
```